# how to make target link work giving different css properities

Tags: css

how to make the folowing change to be a scale transition ? once clicked on the link the expand to happen with scalling effect ?

http://jsfiddle.net/vladicorp/C63nn/5/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<a href="#click">One</a>

<div id="click">
<div id="one">Number One</div>  
<div id="two">Number Two</div>  
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
     #click {
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

#one {
color:yellow;    

}
#two {
color:yellow;    

}

#click:target #one {
    color:red;
    font-size:90px
}

#click:target #two {
    color:blue;
    font-size:420px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add transition in following css segment

```
#click:target #one {
    color:red;
    font-size:90px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

#click:target #two {
    color:blue;
    font-size:420px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C63nn/7/)